# How to do IP whitelisting in Spring Boot 3.1.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot

We did Spring Boot upgrade to 3.1.0 from 2.6.0. The below IP whitelisting doesn't work as many of the methods are deprecated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("192.0.0.1")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to pass IP to whitelist to below code.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> {auth.requestMatchers("/**");
        auth.requestMatchers("","");
        auth.anyRequest().authenticated();})
    .httpBasic(withDefaults()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug after migration to `authorizeHttpRequests()` but Spring Framework Team have fixed it into new version.

[Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter and write logic to get IP from request and filter it

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class IpFilter implements Filter {

   @value("${allowed.ip:}")
   private String whitelistedIp;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String ip = req.getRemoteAddr();  
        if (!ip.equals(whitelistedIp) {
          // Update the logic if you want
          req.reset();
          return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```